# Rails 4 datatables Export to excel file is working but file is not readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

For some reason the excel generated using below code is only working in development and staging mode. In production server the generated excel file using datatables doesn't work and shows warning "Excel could not open xyz.xlsx because some content is unreadable", if generated in production mode. I am using DataTables 1.10.18.

application.js

```
//= require datatables/datatables.min.js
//= require datatables/moment.js
//= require datatables/datetime-moment.js
//= require datatables/datatables_setup.js
```

HTML:

```
<table id="store_orders_table" class="table table-stripped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="bold-detail-text">Customer</th>
                  <th class="bold-detail-text">Order Items</th>
                  <th class="bold-detail-text">Order Date</th>
                  <th class="bold-detail-text">Payment Method</th> 
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% @orders && @orders.each_with_index do |order,index| %> 
                  <tr>
                    <td class="detail-text">
                      <%= order.name rescue "" %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="detail-text" style="min-width:102px;">
                      <%= order.order_item.name %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="detail-text" data-export="<%= order.payment.payment_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>"> 
                      <%= order.payment.payment_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y") rescue ""%>
                    </td>
                    <td class="detail-text">
                      <%= order.payment.payment_method.to_s.titleize rescue "" %>
                    </td> 
                    <td class="detail-text">
                      <%=order.comments %>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

JS:

```
$('#store_orders_table').DataTable( {
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "<i class='detail-text'>No records found</i>"
    },
    pageLength: 100,
    bFilter: true,
    dom: 'Brtipl',
    "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
    buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            filename: 'store_orders_report',
            title: "",
            footer: false,
            header: true,
            text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export as Excel',
            titleAttr: 'Export as EXCEL',
            classAttr: 'pull-right', 
            exportOptions: { 
              orthogonal: 'export', 
              columns: [0,1,2,3], 
              format: {
                  body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                      if( typeof $(node).data('export') !== 'undefined'){
                          data = $(node).data('export');
                      }                 
                      return data;
                  }              
                }
              }
          }
    ],
    columns: [
    { data: "0",render: function (data, type, row) { return data }},
    { data: "1",render: function (data, type, row) { return data }},
    { data: "2",render: function (data, type, row) { return data }},
    { data: "3",render: function (data, type, row) { return data }}, 
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
    {"targets": [ 0 ], "visible": true, "searchable": true },
    {"targets": [ 1 ], "visible": true, "searchable": true },
    {"targets": [ 2 ], "visible": true, "searchable": true },
    {"targets": [ 3 ], "visible": true, "searchable": true }, 
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer here because I didn't find it documented anywhere. After spending hours it worked by changing js_compressor in production.rb. Looks like support for ES5/ES6 is also needed for datatables while precompiling assets. The excel is now able to display all types of characters including support for other language characters. Previously it was failing to open excel because of special characters & some content in japanese.

```
  # Compress JavaScripts
  #config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear html strip tags with `data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");`

```
exportOptions: {
    format: {
        body: function(data, row, column, node) {
            return data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
        }
    }
}
```